# Difficulty mounting an ext4 formated filesystem on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mount

I've formatted and allocated my 30 GB ext4 partition for Steam. After it had been mounted I've tried to install a game (1800 MB) and upon doing so I'm being shown:

> New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with executable permissions.

I'm really confused as to way I can't seem to get executable permissions on this partition. I've tried to remount with:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rwx /var/host/media/removable/sdb2
```

After running this command terminal says:

```
mount point 1 does not exist.
```

Yet I can see it does exist here:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /var/host/media/removable/UUI type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,dirsync,data=ordered) | 30G 10K 29G 1% /var/host/media/removable/UUI /dev/sdb2
```

I've tried to mount with `exec` permissions using the following command:

```
sudo mount -o exec /dev/sdb2 /var/host/media/removable/UUI
```

and I'm unsuccessful in getting this resolved. I've tried unmounting the partition and remounting and I'm not able to get it to mount. It says it can't find it in my `fstab` entries so I added it there following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557556/).

What am I doing wrong?

---

@KamilMaciorowski I have updated this post.
@MichaelBay

I've tried this command

```
chown root /dev/sdb2
```

and command is working but I'm still recieving the error "New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with executable permissions."

I've tried to list the files where the executable is located at and it displays

@jpaugh
@Barton Chittenden updated post and included output of command.

```
@localhost:~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common$ ls -l "/home/euronymous/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Don't Starve Together/"

> total 260
drwxrwxr-x  3 euronymous euronymous   4096 Oct  8 20:13 bin
drwxrwxr-x 76 euronymous euronymous   4096 Oct  9 17:35 cached_mods
drwxrwxr-x 13 euronymous euronymous   4096 Oct  8 20:13 data
-rwxrwxr-x  1 euronymous euronymous 243381 Oct  8 20:04 dontstarve.xpm
drwxrwxr-x 72 euronymous euronymous   4096 Oct 10 14:49 mods
-rwxrwxr-x  1 euronymous euronymous      7 Oct  8 20:12 version.txt
```

Comment: You need to `chown` that new EXT4 partition and that will give you the required rwx permissions. Whenever you create a new partition the owner is *root*, not you (the user), therefore you (the user) have no w or x permissions there and likewise any user process like Steam cannot write to that partition.

Comment: @chris Welcome to [su]! Can you show the result of `ls -l` in the directory where one of your game executables is stored? That should reveal more about the problem.

Comment: The reason that you're seeing `>` when trying to list this file is that the apostrophe in `Don't Starve Together` is being seen by bash as a single quote -- the `>` is prompting you to enter the matching `'`.  Try surrounding the file name with double quotes:  `ls -l "/home/me/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Don't Starve Together/"` (This is also necessary because you have a space in the file name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mount point has `noexec` mount option, which prevents executing files in the mounted filesystem directly.

You need to use `remount` option when you want to change mount options for already mounted filesystem. Using the mount point in your question:

```
mount -o remount,exec /var/host/media/removable/UUI
```

You need to use quotes for path if it contains spaces or characters which would be  expanded by shell. If the path is otherwise incorrect (wrong/non-existent directory or device) [`mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/mount.8.html) command will return an error.